# Snapchat's SnapKit addLoginStatusObserver not listening to events

Tags: objective-c, react-native, snapchat

I'm currently developing a React Native plugin for Snapchat's SnapKit SDK.

I can't seem to get the `addLoginStatusObserver` method to work (detailed here: https://snapkit.com/docs/api/ios/) and I suspect it's my lack of experience with Objective C's protocol/interface/implementation features.

Here's a trimmed down version of the code:

```
...

@interface RNSnapSDKListener : NSObject<SCSDKLoginStatusObserver> {
...
}
- (void)scsdkLoginLinkDidSucceed;
- (void)scsdkLoginLinkDidFail;
- (void)scsdkLoginDidUnlink;
...
@end

@implementation RNSnapSDKListener

- (void)scsdkLoginLinkDidSucceed{
    NSLog(@"[RNSnapSDKListener] Snapchat Did Login!");
}
- (void)scsdkLoginLinkDidFail{
    NSLog(@"[RNSnapSDKListener] Snapchat Did Fail!");
}
- (void)scsdkLoginDidUnlink{
    NSLog(@"[RNSnapSDKListener] Snapchat Did Unlink!");
}

- (void)setDelegate: (RCTEventEmitter*) eventEmitter{
    NSLog(@"[RNSnapSDKListener] Delegate Set!");
}
@end

@implementation RNSnapSDK

...

RCT_EXPORT_MODULE()

RCT_EXPORT_METHOD(initialize){
    RNSnapSDKListener *listener = [[RNSnapSDKListener alloc] init];
    [listener setDelegate:self];
    [SCSDKLoginClient addLoginStatusObserver:listener];
}

RCT_EXPORT_METHOD(login)
{
    [SCSDKLoginClient loginFromViewController:[UIApplication sharedApplication].delegate.window.rootViewController completion:^(BOOL success, NSError * _Nullable error) {
    }];
}

RCT_EXPORT_METHOD(logout: (RCTPromiseResolveBlock)resolve rejecter:(RCTPromiseRejectBlock)reject)
{
    [SCSDKLoginClient unlinkAllSessionsWithCompletion:^(BOOL success) {
        NSLog(@"Logout %s", success ? "true" : "false");
        resolve(NULL);
    }];
}


RCT_EXPORT_METHOD(getUserData: (RCTPromiseResolveBlock)resolve rejecter:(RCTPromiseRejectBlock)reject)
{

    NSString *graphQLQuery = @"{me{externalId, displayName, bitmoji{avatar}}}";

    NSDictionary *variables = @{@"page": @"bitmoji"};

    [SCSDKLoginClient fetchUserDataWithQuery:graphQLQuery
        variables:variables
        success:^(NSDictionary *resources) {
            NSDictionary *data = resources[@"data"];
            resolve(data);
        } failure:^(NSError * error, BOOL isUserLoggedOut) {
            NSLog(@"%@",[error localizedDescription]);
            NSLog(@" %s", isUserLoggedOut ? "true" : "false");

            if(isUserLoggedOut){
                [SCSDKLoginClient loginFromViewController:[UIApplication sharedApplication].delegate.window.rootViewController completion:^(BOOL success, NSError * _Nullable error) {
                }];
            }else{
                reject(@"error", [error localizedDescription], error);
            }
        }];
}

NSURL *saved;

RCT_EXPORT_METHOD(authenticateDeepLink: (NSString *)url)
{
    NSURL *finalUrl = [NSURL URLWithString:url];
    saved = finalUrl;

    [SCSDKLoginClient application:[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:finalUrl options:[NSMutableDictionary dictionary]];

}

...

@end
```

.initialize() is called inside the React Native module, and the setDelegate() method is called successfully (printing out "Delegate set" - this is for the react-native event bridge), but the other [RNSnapSDKListener]s dont print when they should (after logging in or logging out)

Is this something I'm doing wrong with objective-c or some other misuse of Snapchat's SDK?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The problem ended up being that the `RNSnapSDKListener *listener` needed to be declared as a global variable and initialized inside initialize() - not entirely sure why though - something with garbage collection maybe?